# How can I solve Working Time Calculation Problem in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list which consists of different students' check-in check-out dates and times like below:

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy0zQ.png)

My friend wrote a code to calculate work hour of each students per day. Program prints day count, dates and work hour of working more than 11 hours and less than 7 hours.

You can see the result page here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q429a.png)

I have to write a program which calculates work hour per day for each student. Problem is that students check in and out multiple times in a day so I have to sum this in and outs for each day.

Comment: I haven't gone through the code but if you think the issue is that Pre_Daily_WorkDate  isn't being reset then at the beginning of the loop set the variable to null.

Comment: You should rethink the whole solution. Don't wind up in lost cases. Sidenote: Avoid Else if possible. Always avoid ElseIf or you're doing spaghetti programming.

Comment: Liz is doing two parallel sessions on the same day?

Comment: ...following on from that - if that's an error in your sample data, it it assumed that the input data is "perfect"?  Eg. always sorted by pupil then date-time, and always has a matching "out" for every "in" ?  What are the day-counting rules for when a session spans two days (or does that never happen)?

Comment: @Bee_Riii I tried to do that but when I assign it zero, program doesn't give proper calculation too.

Comment: @StureS I didn't like whole code either. It seems so bad written but since I have no idea about VBA, I couldn't write a code for my purpose from scratch.

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry, I notice that mistake now. I changed sample data in first message. Parallel check-in and out is impossible but one can check in and out multiple times in a day. Because of this, I can't sum this multiple in outs for each day.  Yes outs always match with in because it is id card system. It is like company's in out system

Comment: Are you able to share a representative set of data (suitably anonymized of course)?  Not sure I feel like typing my own set...

Comment: @TimWilliams I couldn't add Excel to first message but I added sample table.

Comment: There's no easy way for me to copy/paste that.  Can you share an Excel via onedrive/dropbox/google drive/whatever you have?

Comment: @TimWilliams https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p14dw07Ms3a5n6J_RAYb1jJSU0AyOM0s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What does "no record" signify?  Can those lines be ignored?

Comment: @TimWilliams It means that person didn't come to the lecture at that day. It can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up a bit long/complex with the error-flagging...

Code posted below but it makes more sense with the correct layout so there's a working copy here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P_Ld6ZtaektVGlAkK_GXHxikSu4_ZJSa/view?usp=sharing

Class Module `LogData`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public lastRow As Long
Public lastType As String
Public lastDate As Date
Public totalTime As Double    'fractional day
```

Main module:

```vb
Sub ReviewTimes()
    Const NO_RECORD As String = "No Record"
    Dim rw As Range, dict As Object, dict2 As Object, dt As Date, who, inout As String, k, lastType As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, i As Long, rngFlag As Range, hrs, rngResults As Range, m, resultRow As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    '#### Keep col E clear for flagging errors in input data ####
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A4:E" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Rows
        If Application.CountA(rw) >= 3 Then 'row has data...
            
            dt = rw.Cells(1).Value
            k = rw.Cells(3).Value & "~" & Format(rw.Cells(1).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") 'dictionary key
            inout = Trim(rw.Cells(4).Value)
            Set rngFlag = rw.Cells(5)
            rngFlag.ClearContents       'clear any previous flag
            
            'ignoring "no record" rows...
            If inout <> NO_RECORD Then
                If Not dict.exists(k) Then
                    'first time seeing this Pupil+Date combination
                    If inout = "In" Then
                        Set dict(k) = LogEntry(rw.Row, inout, dt)   'start tracking this day+pupil
                    ElseIf inout = "Out" Then
                        rngFlag.Value = "No prior 'In' record!" 'flag mismatch
                    End If
                Else
                    'seem this Pupil+Date combination before - keep tracking times
                    lastType = dict(k).lastType
                    Select Case inout
                    Case "In"
                        If lastType = "In" Then
                            'two "in"'s in a row - flag prior orphan record
                            ws.Cells(dict(k).lastRow, "E") = "No matching 'out' record!"
                        ElseIf lastType = "Out" Then
                            dict(k).lastType = "In"
                        End If
                        dict(k).lastDate = dt 'start/restart the clock...
                    Case "Out"
                        If lastType = "In" Then
                            dict(k).totalTime = dict(k).totalTime + (dt - dict(k).lastDate) 'add time
                            dict(k).lastType = "Out"
                        ElseIf lastType = "Out" Then
                            rngFlag = "No matching 'in' record!" 'flag this orphan record
                        End If
                    End Select
                    dict(k).lastRow = rw.Row
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    
    
    'now summarize all of the individual pupil+day times
    Set rngResults = ws.Range("H3").Resize(1000, 7)
    rngResults.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    rngResults.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents 'clear previous results but not headers
    resultRow = 2 'start here
    
    For Each k In dict
        who = Split(k, "~")(0)
        dt = Split(k, "~")(1)
        hrs = Round(dict(k).totalTime * 24, 1) 'hours
        
        Debug.Print who, dt, hrs
        
        'flag any remaining orphan "In" records
        If dict(k).lastType = "In" Then
            ws.Cells(dict(k).lastRow, "E") = "No matching 'out' record!"
        End If
        
        If hrs >= 11 Or hrs <= 7 Then
            'see if we already have a row for this pupil
            m = Application.Match(who, rngResults.Columns(1), 0)
            If IsError(m) Then 'no row: add them in
                m = resultRow
                rngResults.Columns(1).Cells(m).Value = who
                resultRow = resultRow + 1 'next name goes here
            End If
            With rngResults.Cells(m, 1).Offset(0, IIf(hrs >= 11, 1, 4)) 'where to put the data
                .Value = .Value + 1 'increment the count
                AddIt .Offset(0, 1), dt
                .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "@" 'edit:format as text
                AddIt .Offset(0, 2), Format(hrs / 24, "h:mm") 'formatted
            End With
         End If
    Next k
    
End Sub

'"factory" function - create and populate an instance of LogData
Function LogEntry(rw As Long, CheckType As String, dt As Date) As LogData
    Dim rv As New LogData
    rv.lastRow = rw
    rv.lastType = CheckType
    rv.lastDate = dt
    Set LogEntry = rv
End Function

'utility for adding a value to a cell (after a newline if cell already has content)
Sub AddIt(c As Range, v)
    c.Value = c.Value & IIf(Len(c.Value) > 0, vbLf, "") & v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, code works like a charm! And it is very good that it shows mismatching in and outs cause I don't even know that is possible. I am trying to understand the code right now. There is just one thing, hours in integer form and I don't quite understand how to convert it like hh:mm. I tried Format(hrs; "hh:mm") but it doens't work.

Comment: You need to convert the hours back to a fractional day by dividing by 24 - see edit above.

Comment: I tried it too, but I don't know why, when there is couple hours in cell, it doesn't convert first hour like that:
"24.10.2020
5.10.2020" "0,283333333333333
7:20"

Comment: I have sent mail.